# Android shared element "hero" transitions when obscured

Tags: android, animation, shared-element-transition

With Android Lollipop we can do shared element transitions on images so that when you open the "detail" view you can animate an image to expand to a larger size in the new screen.

This all works fine but when an image appears underneath a navigation component (e.g. SearchBar on Google Photos or a tab layout), the enter and exit animation isn't as clean as it should be.

On the (re)enter animation for example you can see the image being drawn and then suddenly the tab layout will appear above it in a very jerky way. An example would be if you clicked on any of the top 3 images in the below screenshot.

Has anyone got any tips on how to make this smoother?

[image: Example image]

Comment: Barry, this could be related to [Issue 192339: AppBarLayout+TabLayout glitch in shared element transition](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192339). I have no workaround, just stumbled upon it during my own investigations for something else.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Thanks for that. That looks exactly like the issue I was trying to describe. I've starred it so that I get an update when the "future release" is known